# Customize the Exoplayer Play and Pause buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer

I'm a beginner to android. I want to change the location of the play and pause buttons in center of the ExoPlayer view surface like as Facebook. In here I create a the `MainActivity` with Exoplayer and three `textviews` for the scrolling purpose.

I inserted a library called

"compile `com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.4.4`" to the `build.gradle` (Module app). Then I used it in my `activity_main`. Following is my code, and also I kindly appreciate for a solution.

activity_main.xml code

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fillViewport="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                                <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="350dp"
                                    android:id="@+id/simple_expo_player">

                                </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Hello world"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Hello world"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Hello world"
                                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">


                        </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.theace.videoplayer;


import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.DefaultExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.extractor.ExtractorsFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.AdaptiveTrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.DefaultTrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelection;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.trackselection.TrackSelector;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.BandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultBandwidthMeter;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SimpleExoPlayerView simpleExoPlayerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initUi();
    }

    public void initUi(){

// 1. Create a default TrackSelector
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

// 2. Create the player

        SimpleExoPlayer player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(getApplicationContext(), trackSelector);

// 3. Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(getApplicationContext(), Util.getUserAgent(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.theace.videoplayer"));
// 4. Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
        ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
// 5. This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse("https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"),dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

// 6. Prepare the player with the source.
        player.prepare(videoSource);
        simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.simple_expo_player);
        simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/simple_expo_player">

    </com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Play"/>
    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Pause"/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> Check this